# Making a solid contour using seaborn in Python

Tags: python, plot, seaborn

I have checked [this tutorial](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html) for plotting contours using `seaborn, kdeplot`.
The contours in this example have [layers inside](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrlp6.png) but I want to plot a solid contour without any layer or line inside of it.
I mean, I would like to fill the contour to have an even object not a contour with too many lines inside of it.
Could any one help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are referring to a `kdeplot` here. This usually needs some contours to make sense. I.e. from a single contour you cannot know the distribution of the data.

But if you still want to have a single contour, you may use the `n_levels` argument and set it to `1`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(10)
import seaborn as sns; sns.set(color_codes=True)
mean, cov = [0, 2], [(1, .5), (.5, 1)]
x, y = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean, cov, size=50).T

ax = sns.kdeplot(x, y, n_levels=1, cmap="Purples_d", shade=True, shade_lowest=True)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: and could you tell me how to change background color? As I cange the `cmap` both contour and BG are changed.

Comment: Set `shade_lowest` to `False` and change the color of the axes (`ax.set_facecolor("limegreen")`).

Comment: where should I add this extra line?`ax.set_facecolor("limegreen")`